# Regex (JavaScript) for parsing function names from C++ file doesn't work in certain whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a small JS routine which uses a regular expression to obtain function names with their params from a C++ file. The function names are obtained without their return value. Everything is OK except it doesn't recognize those cases when there is a space between function name and the opening parenthesis of the parameter list `(`. For example, if a C++ file has the following contents:

```
int func1(lh, rh);
void func2(lh, rh);

int r = func1(10, 20);
```

The routine returns

```
func1(lh, rh)
func2(lh, rh)
func1(10, 20)
```

But if we place a space, after the function name then this function is not recognized as function. For example, if declare `func3` as below

```
void func3    (lh, rh);
```

then `func3` is not included in the return value.

I search for functions in a C++ file using the variable `searchRule`

```
var searchRule = /(operator(?:\s*).+|~?\w+)\(.*\)/g
```

How can I change the `searchRule` regular expression so that the routine could be able to deal with spaces after function name as well?

Comment: You could have phrased this more succinctly but the votes for 'unclear what you're asking' are unfair IMO. You're just stuck on a regex adjustment to allow for whitespace between a function name and opening bracket?

Answer (score 1):

```
//                                         ---
var searchRule = /(operator(?:\s*).+|~?\w+)\s*\(.*\)/g
//                                         ---
```

`\s*` = *zero or more occurences of any whitespace character*

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/DWtfXp/2/)